# Calculate SD using svysd inside subgroup analysis of svysby using survey package

Tags: r, survey, standard-deviation

I would like to get the standard deviation of subgroup analysis of weighted survey data. Svymean does not have a problem, but only returns SE.

```
svyby(~LBXSATSI, ~RIAGENDR, design =NHANES_design, svymean, na= TRUE)
```

Once the function is changed from svymean to svysd, I get an error as below.

**error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 't': $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors**

Is there a different way to calculate the SD?

Answer (score 0):

when i follow [the loading page here](http://asdfree.com/national-health-and-nutrition-examination-survey-nhanes.html), the function `svyvar` works fine.  the `?svysd` help page says this just needs `sqrt()` to get the same answer.  `svysd` doesn't appear compatible with `svyby` because of the line `rval <- t(sapply(results, unwrap))`  ... you could e-mail the maintainer to let them know

Answer (score 0):

Because `svysd` doesn't return the right sort of object to work with the `survey` package functions, you can only use it with `svyby` if you don't ask for standard errors (use `keep.var=FALSE`).  That should be fine, because `svysd` doesn't even return standard errors.

Using an example from the survey package help:

```
> svyby(~enroll,~stype, rclus1,svysd)
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 't': $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
> svyby(~enroll,~stype, rclus1,svysd,keep.var=FALSE)
  stype statistic
E     E  141.1100
H     H  843.1026
M     M  355.2013
```

It's helpful when you ask questions like this to say what package `svysd` is from (`jtools`). I knew it wasn't from the `survey` package, but I didn't know where to find it at first.